# Getting an excerpt from HTML in PHP

Tags: php, html

I need to get a short excerpt of news items written in HTML to show on my front page. Obviously I can't use something as simple as `substr` because it might leave tags unclosed or even leave half a tag.

Which is easier:

- Converting the HTML to decent looking plain text and take a piece of that
- Taking the beginning from the HTML and closing any unclosed tags at the cutoff (will this always look OK?)

And how would I go about implementing the chosen solution?

Comment: A third way would be to parse the HTML, for [example with DOMDocument which takes care of the tags](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29323396/367456).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simplest way is to strip all HTML from the item text using `strip_tags()` before truncating it.

Comment: Using this now for automatically generated excerpts. It's not the best, but it's ok, since I provided news posters with special markup to specify their own excerpts.

Answer (score 3):

I would take the 2nd option if it's important to retain the HTML structure of the original news item.

A simple way to implement this would be to run your fragment through [Tidy](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php) to close off any unclosed tags. In particular, see the [tidy::cleanRepair](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.cleanrepair.php) method.

Answer (score 3):

This excerpts down to the first paragraph without cutting words and appends optional trail.

$excerpt = self::excerpt_paragraph($html, 180)

```
/**
* excerpt first paragraph from html content
* 
**/
public static function excerpt_paragraph($html, $max_char = 100, $trail='...' )
{
    // temp var to capture the p tag(s)
    $matches= array();
    if ( preg_match( '/<p>[^>]+<\/p>/', $html, $matches) )
    {
        // found <p></p>
        $p = strip_tags($matches[0]);
    } else {
        $p = strip_tags($html);
    }
    //shorten without cutting words
    $p = self::short_str($p, $max_char );

    // remove trailing comma, full stop, colon, semicolon, 'a', 'A', space
    $p = rtrim($p, ',.;: aA' );

    // return nothing if just spaces or too short
    if (ctype_space($p) || $p=='' || strlen($p)<10) { return ''; }

    return '<p>'.$p.$trail.'</p>';
}
//

/**
* shorten string but not cut words
* 
**/
public static function short_str( $str, $len, $cut = false )
{
    if ( strlen( $str ) <= $len ) { return $str; }
    $string = ( $cut ? substr( $str, 0, $len ) : substr( $str, 0, strrpos( substr( $str, 0, $len ), ' ' ) ) );
    return $string;
}
//
```

Answer (score 2):

Hello I guess what you are looking for is called website scraping.
Here is how you can scrape a website;
Use a library PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser download here [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group%5Fid=218559)

And finally here is the code how you can scrape Slashdot

```
// Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://slashdot.org/');

// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('div.article') as $article) {
    $item['title']   = $article->find('div.title', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['intro']   = $article->find('div.intro', 0)->plaintext;
    $item['details'] = $article->find('div.details', 0)->plaintext;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

print_r($articles);
```

Comment: Not using this in this situation, but helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You could try parsing your data to XML and then truncating only the "pure" text nodes.

Note: This solution forces the input to be valid XML and to be always in about the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's better to take, for example, first two paragraphs by using regex with groups and lazy quantifiers.

```
function excerpt_from_html($str) {
    $re = '/(<p>\X*?<\/p>)\X*?(<p>\X*?<\/p>)/u';
    preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
    return $matches[1] . $matches[2];
}
```

Or you can take 3-4 paragraphs and make a decision how many of them to show up based on the length of the excerpt.