# Google news feed content

Tags: php, xml, feed

So lets say i have a google news feed, like this: https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=no_no&hl=no&q=%22something%22&output=atom&num=1

Grabbing the title, author and link would be easy, but how would i go around getting say the first 200 characters of the content? its full of html, and mixed in with the title and author aswell.

i could use strip_tags on it, but it would still be a mess.

Any way to make google return a ['description'] maybe?

or is there perhaps any other good news feeds that gives me the content in a way thats easier to manage?

[edit]

Update on how i ended up doing it.

```
$news = @simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents('https://news.google.com/news/feeds?pz=1&cf=all&ned=no_no&hl=no&q=%22molde+fotballklubb%22+OR+%22tornekrattet%22+OR+%22mfk%22+OR+%22oddmund+bjerkeset%22+-%22moss%22&output=atom&num=1'),  'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);

        $data = get_object_vars($news->{'entry'});
        $test = explode('<font size="-1">', $data['content']);
        $link = get_object_vars($data['link']);

        $return['title']        = strip_tags($test[0]);
        $return['author']       = strip_tags($test[1]);
        $return['description'] = strip_tags($test[2]);
        $return['link']         = $link['@attributes']['href'];
```

It is still not working properly, but thats because the feed gives me the content in different ways all the time. Sometimes the content of the news article itself will just be metadata like the authors and image descriptions.

And the breaking it up by html tags when the html have changes from time to time causes some problems. But i cant figure out any othe way of doing it with this feed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting an excerpt from HTML in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771421/getting-an-excerpt-from-html-in-php) - Please use the search first, this is only one of many possibilities. It's okay to ask your own question, however, please make clear what you tried so far, reference the related questions, explain what didn't work for you (like that `strip_tags` is not what you're looking for) and what you're looking for instead and why it's not possible for you to achieve that - thank you! (you will get much better answers, believe me)

Comment: `strip_tags` was exactly what i was looking for, to get rid of the html tags. But obviously not for the rest of the problems (which i never stated it would be).

Comment: Just seeing you edited your question. Instead add your solution as an answer below. That will also allow you to accept it later and mark the question as solved. This is how it works - and is perfectly accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading the HTML in a DOMDocument instance and extract the parts you need, or use a wrapper for it like Goutte which makes it a lot easier to extract portions you need.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte